# How to show fraction in svg if i am using text for now any other alternative using svg

Tags: svg

I want the text to show a number in the form a/b.
How can I do in SVG`<text></text>`

E.g. [image]

Answer (score 1):

You could display it via unicode superscript and subscript characters like this.

```html
<svg>
  <text x="20" y="30" font-family="Cambria" font-size="20px">Fraction: &#179;⁄&#8322;</text>
</svg>
```

or this where dx is used to make the letters appear in the same place.

```html
<svg>
  <text x="20" y="30" font-family="Cambria" font-size="20px">Fraction: <tspan dx="0 -11.5 -11.5">&#179;&#8213;&#8322;</tspan></text>
</svg>
```